# How do I copy an access database file with my application?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, clickonce

In my Visual Basic Application, I have an access database file that I am using.  It shows up in the solution explorer window.  Everything works great until I install.  The database file doesn't go with the installation for some reason.  I guess I need to edit the connection string during runtime, but I am not sure.  I have not done anything like this before, and I cannot find the information about it.

If someone could send me to a tutorial or give a brief explanation of how to use an access database once the application has been installed.

When my program runs, it creates a directory in

```
User\App Data\Roaming\CreatedFolder\Resources\DatabaseFile.accdb
```

So how do I set this path without knowing the full path up to App Data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL database deployment for VB.NET app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253978/sql-database-deployment-for-vb-net-app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```vb
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

or

```vb
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA")
```

They both should return something similar to

```
C:\Users\Gord\AppData\Roaming
```

so you can build your connection string like this:

```vb
Dim dbPath = _
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & _
        "\CreatedFolder\Resources\DatabaseFile.accdb"
Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
```

Comment: I get errors when I try adding that to the connection string.

Comment: I used the wizard to setup my database connection, so how would I change the connection string at runtime?

Comment: @xRuhRohx Perhaps `My.Settings.Item("DatabaseFileConnectionString") = connStr` might do it. Check the "Settings" tab in the project properties page to confirm the name of the setting.

Comment: Ok I will give that a shot.

Comment: Ok that worked, thank you much.  Is it safe to edit the connection string at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this would be to:

1. Select `Add New Data Source . . .` from the Data Source window in Visual Studio
2. Select `Database` from the list that appears, and click next
3. Click next
4. In the `Choose your data connection` page of the wizard, click `New connection`
5. Choose `Microsoft Access Database File` from the listbox and click next
6. Choose a copy of the database file that is not in your directory and enter any login information
7. Click OK
8. Now Visual Studio will ask you:

   The connection you selected uses a local data file that is not in the
    current project. Would you like to copy the file to the project and
    and modify the connection?

   If you copy the data file to your project, it will be copied to the project's
    output directory every time you run the application. Press F1 for
    information on controlling this behavior.

Click "Yes," and Visual Studio will add the database to your project and make a connection string that points to the copied database.

9. Now you will probably want to save the connection string in App.Config so that you don't have to rebuild it every time you want to use the database. Most likely this will save a connection string that uses `|DataDirectory|`. Modify the contents of this page as you see fit.
10. Procede through the rest of the wizard and configure your database as you need it.

The wizard should configure the connection string and build information such that your application will work no matter where you take it.

EDIT - My connection string as it is saved in App.config looks like

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SOAccessDatabase.My.MySettings.Students_2000formatConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Students_2000format.mdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

I also have the database file's Build Action set to "Copy Always."

Comment: The issue I run into when I leave it as |DataDirectory| it creates a folder inside the Local folder in AppData and for some reason doesn't copy the database over to it.  I always get an error.

Comment: This is what happens when I install and Run ....  'C:\Users\Neil\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\KBBE6L8Y.4H8\2X1QXHV5.A2H\gulb..tion_20d7bfc1bd30efa8_0001.0000_dbc5cc6b3df538bc\Data\Resources\TML.accdb' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Comment: @xRuhRohx, look at the edit and see if it helps. This application accesses the data just fine as it is configured now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Our connection strings are very similar, I think I discovered why it is not working for me.  Right now I am installing as a click once application.

Comment: That didn't change anything either.  I thought I was doing something good by using a database, but this is too much of a headache.