# Making installation with access database

Tags: vb.net, installation

I want to make a installation file in visual studio 2013 with database including.

How to do that ?

When i go to publish tab i see this

[image]

My database was stored in project resources .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the Build action of the database file to "content"

- In solution explorer click in your database file
- in properties window check the Build action property and change it to content
- check the publish window now , you have to see your database file included

See the picture below
http://s23.postimg.org/hkgaxcbqz/stack.png

Comment: thanks for your fast answer but after installing i got this error
http://pokit.org/get/?41f934f6920357161324a37a54c78b88.jpg

Comment: it seems that searching your database in this specific path and not in the application statrtup path.

Comment: please post the code that you call the database file in your program

Comment: also take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995594/how-do-i-copy-an-access-database-file-with-my-application

Comment: My problem here is i'm not using the connection string at all. I use bindingsource and navigator for adding data.

Comment: ok you are right i have compile it and publish it and i have the same issue that caused because of the data folder that doesn't created automatically see the picture and this will work for sure i have tested http://s30.postimg.org/3u2kpsn81/stack2.png

Comment: thank you very much for trying to help me friend. But the problems seems here http://pokit.org/get/?41991b07eae94fe85d569bbfc2907fa6.jpg in the full path option. I think i did mistake there and even when i set required data it still wont be in folder http://pokit.org/get/?6f0c9c7cc0cf44f8626eaf0163dafa27.jpg

Comment: As i see you have drop the database in your resource directory in the solution explorer mine is in the root directory also goto to tOrg.exe.config file and see the line that contains the following line connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|........ this is the problem

Comment: Yes and what after i put it like this "            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\WeekDatabase.base.accdb"
" do i need to copy manually database in some folder or not touch anything else ?

Comment: No the strange thing that in my setup after i publish it works well i have attach the complete setup of application see the picture http://s12.postimg.org/f3twmpp7h/stack3.png and it works for sure because when i rename the test.accdb to test.accdb.back it crushes so the file that it uses it take it from the correct path. my suggestion check again the content variable , republish the app

Comment: I would really appreciate if we can continue this conversation on skype or teamviewer if i don't be able to finish this tomorrow.  Skype: t3choo

Comment: sure lets give it a try