# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2012 database remotely

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, localdb

Was able to connect to my SQL Server 2012 database using localhost with no problem storing it in the App_Data folder. My connection string was...

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bookingsandpreorders.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

However when I hosted my site on another/remote server I got the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The system cannot find the file specified
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

I thought it may be the connection string after looking at connection strings.com so I tried...

```
Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\bookingsandpreorders.mdf;Database=bookingsandpreorders.mdf;
```

However now I just get another error...

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I've watched and read a seemingly endless amount about this error mainly involving configuring firewall, tcp port... all of which have made no difference.

I think I've made a rookie error as I've not got much experience with SQL Server Express. any suggestions?

Comment: does your sql require username and password? Secondly, have you included your db in output build?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL database deployment for VB.NET app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12253978/sql-database-deployment-for-vb-net-app)

Comment: Are you sure you have SQL Express instance installed? If all you have is LocalDB, then you won't be able to connect to .\SQLExpress instance.

Comment: The `AttachDBFilename` property is meant for development. If you have installed SQLExpress, you should really actually properly attach the database in there.

Comment: No password as it uses windows authentication - would it help if I created one? 

Yes my database files (.mdf & .ldf) are in an App_Data folder in the output. 

I'm pretty sure I have an instance installed according to this article [Determine Whether the Database Engine Is Installed and Started](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366339.aspx).

I've also attached the DB in sql server management tools but it doesnt make a difference.

Comment: Your original connection string was for LocalDb, a single user/ single instance version of SQL Express. Pretty much the whole string needs to be converted to SQL Express. You also need to actually install and configure SQL Express to use your database.

Comment: There is a chance that the real problem is that you do not have LocalDb installed on the host, and your original string is fine. Then your AppPool might need to run as a user with adequate permissions as well as load user profile and setProfileEnvironment true.